# Uses of ocelot in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have made few ocelots from ocelot DNA sampler feature from a minecraft mod named polycraft world. Are there any uses of these tamed cats? Can they attack mobs at night?

Comment: From my experience, they are like sheeps or cows, just without the wool.

Comment: "Ocelots are like cows, just without the wool."

Comment: But to get serious again: The wiki lists all the things that ocelots do. Are you asking what they can do in that mod?

Comment: I was wondering if there are any features i don't know and wanted to check if these apply to the mod i am playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well they attack chickens and baby turtles, they stalk the animals before chasing it down. They can kill through a fence or a door. Creepers and phantoms are both scared of ocelots. They keep a distance of 16 blocks between them and the ocelot. The ocelots also are immune to fall damage, but still avoid falling off cliffs high enough to normally cause fall damage.

These are all the features from vanilla Minecraft, but the mod you're using may alter those features.